# Quantum Bell-Type Inequalities

Tags: reference-request, quantum-computing, quantum-information

I'm curious if someone could recommend some supplementary material for gaining a deeper understanding of the paper : "[Some Results and Problems on Quantum Bell-Type Inequalities - Tsirelson](http://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/download/hadron.html)".

Specifically something that may elaborate a tad more on the geometric interpretation of Bell-Type inequalities. Perhaps a primer paper or relevant textbook that goes into more detail on these matters. I'd appreciate any/all feedback. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Werner and Wolf's paper "Bell inequalities and entanglement" (http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0107093) gives a brief and readable introduction and discussion of Bell inequalities as faces of correlation polytopes.

Answer (score 6):

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0404097) by Barrett et al. gives a fairly intuitive description of non-signalling correlations (what Tsirelson calls non-interacting systems). Sections II.A. and II.B.1. are the most useful and easy to read, the rest is more heavy stuff.

Answer (score 5):

I'd mention a recent review "From Bell Inequalities to Tsirelson's Theorem: A Survey" by David Avis, Sonoko Moriyama, Masaki Owari, IEICE Trans. Fund. Electron. Comm. Comput. Sci., vol. E92-A, No.5, pp.1254-1267, 2009 ([here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4887)).

Comment: At least, they have considered paper you cited, used a construction with Clifford algebra from that ...

Answer (score 4):

I haven't read the paper you linked to but a must must read paper on Bell Inequalities is 
[**Hidden variables and the two theorems of John Bell *by N. David Mermin***](http://rmp.aps.org/abstract/RMP/v65/i3/p803_1).

He has written [a lot on Bell Inequalities](http://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?client=ubuntu&channel=cs&q=n%20david%20mermin&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&hl=en&tab=ws).